# Use of multi exception catch in Java 7

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Other than grouping similar exception types, what are the other advantages of handling multiple exception in one catch block over handling it using base Exception class?

Why to prefer this :

```
try{
        //some code
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e1 | IOException e2){

    }
```

Over this (This is less verbose) :

```
 try{
            //some code
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catching generic Exception will also catch NullPointerException, IndexOutOfBoundsException and other exceptions that you generally don't want to catch. By catching the specific exceptions you want to handle you can avoid these situations.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

The two pieces of code are not equivalent.

The first one catches ONLY `FileNotFoundException`, `IOException` and their subclasses<sup>1</sup>.

The second one catches the above PLUS all other checked exceptions AND all unchecked exceptions (apart from `Error` and its subclasses).  So:

- You would be catching a whole bunch of exceptions that are  *typically* a result of programming error; e.g. null pointers, problems with indexing and so on.
- You are effectively "turning off" the checked exception mechanism which would give you a compile time error if you forgot to handle some checked exception; e.g. `SQLException`.  Now *at this point in time* your code probably doesn't throw any checked exceptions apart from the ones you are catching (in version #1).  But what happens if you modify the code to call some method that (say) `throws SQLException`:

  - With version #1 ... compilation error.  Ooops, but you can fix that.
  - With version #2 ... no compilation error.  Lets hope that your unit and systems tests are good enough to pick up the problem.

So, to answer your question ...

> Why to prefer [version #1] ... over [version #2] (This is less verbose) :

You should prefer the one that is correct, not the one that is less verbose.  The second version will catch exceptions that you (probably) don't intend to be caught, which makes it incorrect.

Prefer version #1.

---

<sup>1 - Note that `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException` so you could rewrite version #1 to catch `IOException` only.  If "verbosity" is your main focus, then catching BOTH `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException` is verbose.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Well it's more about being efficient and effective in your exception handling, you've got quite a few ways of doing things like this. Also keep in mind that when you're working on a project big or small depending on what you're doing attempting to use some thing like

```
try{


 }(catch Exception e);
```

on a program (for example) using Encryption you'll get a ton of errors, like

```
NoSuchAlgorithmException 

InvalidKeyException
```

And much more because that base Exception can't handle them.

When you use a compiler and each one is different... but in general they will all give you some form of a warning basically telling you " Hey Exception e wont handle this"

You'll also see that you'll have the ability to do things like this.

```
public setStringExample(string example) throws IOException, Exception, NullPointerExcetptiopn {

 }
```

Java in a lot of ways forces you to account for most things which isn't really a bad thing I guess lol..

TL;DR The overall point I'm trying to make is that Exception handling should be done properly and efficiently which is learned over time, don't try to catch some thing that isn't their and don't try to avoid catching some thing that probably will be!

Comment: Actually both NoSuchAlgorithmException and InvalidKeyException are subclasses of Exception and will be caught by a generic catch (Exception e).